# Cordova camera plugin selecting all media always opens google drive

Tags: cordova

I'm using camera plugin to select files from phone.

```
 navigator.camera.getPicture(
       function (imageURI) {},
       function (err) {},
       {
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
          quality: 100,
          sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
          mediaType: Camera.MediaType.ALLMEDIA
       }
    );
```

Calling this displays a list of programs to use for selecting a file, but when I clicked on google Drive it started instantly opening Drive every other time i try to run this, and there is no defaults set on Drive app, and I cant find a way to open selection menu like it was first time.

Comment: This is not code problem. May be you also clicked on `always` where plugin asks options to open which media.

Comment: Try to uninstall your application and then again install.

Comment: Hey, tried reinstalling, it doesn't help. As i recall i clicked only once, and my app as-well as Drive app doesn't have any defaults set. I'm running Android 5.1 and Cordova 3.7.0. Camera plugin version is 0.3.4

Comment: can you post a screenshot?